# add/combine json array to array in JSON file php

Tags: php, json, array-push

I have been trying to solve this problem for the better part of two days with no success.  I am trying combine/add to a json array that is stored in a .json file on my server using php.

**This is a short version of what I'm trying to combine.**

box.json:

```
[{"date":"25.4.2013 10:40:10"},{"comment":"some text"},{"comment":"some more text"}]
```

posted json:

```
[{"date":"25.4.2013 10:45:15"},{"comment":"another quote"},{"comment":"quote"}]
```

**This is what I need.**

```
[{"date":"25.4.2013 10:40:10"},{"comment":"some text"},{"comment":"some more text"},
{"date":"25.4.2013 10:45:15"},{"comment":"another quote"},{"comment":"quote"}]
```

**This is what I get. (an array inside an array)**

```
[{"date":"25.4.2013 10:40:10"},{"comment":"some text"},{"comment":"some more text"},
[{"date":"25.4.2013 10:45:15"},{"comment":"another quote"},{"comment":"quote"}]]
```

**This is my code:**

```
<?php
$sentArray = $_POST['json'];
$boxArray = file_get_contents('ajax/box.json');
$sentdata = json_decode($sentArray);
$getdata = json_decode($boxArray);
$sentdata[] = $getdata;   /* I also tried array_push($sentdata, $getdata); */
$json = json_encode($sentdata);
$fsize = filesize('ajax/box.json');
if ($fsize <= 5000){
    if (json_encode($json) != null) { /* sanity check */
    $file = fopen('ajax/box.json' ,'w+');
    fwrite($file, $json);
    fclose($file);
}else{
    /*rest of code*/
}
?>
```

Please help my sanity is starting to come in to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$sentdata[] = $getdata;   /* I also tried array_push($sentdata, $getdata); */
```

Try:

```
$combinedData = array_merge($sentData, $getData);
$json = json_encode($combinedData);
```

By using [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) you're combining the arrays into one instead of adding one array as a value into the other.

Note that I changed the name of your resulting data - try to avoid variables with the same name and different capitalization, it will make things much easier to understand (for you and for future developers supporting your code).

Cheers

Comment: I need to add values, It should allow for duplicates. And you are right my my naming practices are messy.  I'm a designer learning to develop. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Nick, it will allow for duplicates since you are using Objects as values and not scalars.  Let me know if it's unclear how to use this.

Comment: I tried running array merge awhile ago and it didn't work (I must have done something wrong), but it appears you are correct it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is your problem

```
$sentdata[] = $getdata;
```

use `foreach`

```
foreach($getdata as $value)
    $sentdata[] = $value;
```

**UPDATE:**
but i think you need this for `$sentdata` not `$getdata`

```
foreach($senttdata as $value)
    $getdata[] = $value;
```

then put `$getdata` to your file.

Comment: Iteration is not the best answer here - depending on the size of the data set this could become very expensive.

Comment: @Madbreaks is there a any other way ? what is `array_merge` exactly do ? just write a name , and your code is best ? what is this function exactly do ?

Comment: I explained what array_merge does. I also provided a link to the official PHP docs. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: data set will write over at 5kb, would it be a problem?

Comment: It will be *extremely* inefficient - this is what's called a brute-force solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$box = json_decode(file_get_contents('ajax/box.json'));
$posted = json_decode($_POST['json']);
$merge = array_merge ((array)$box,(array)$posted);
```

Casting (array) prevent error if $box or $posted become null or false, it will be an empty array